# Location wildcard for nginx block

Tags: nginx-location

Very new to nginx config, i'm trying to configure a location block to use a wildcard after "/dev/"
Example of what works below:

```
location /agent-d-ccp/dev/getcalltypelist/GEQ {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header x-apigw-api-id XXXX;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    set $backend XXXX;
    proxy_pass $backend/dev/getcalltypelist/GEQ;
 }
```

But I need a wildcard for anything after "/dev" because "getcalltypelist" will change and so will "GEQ"

```
location ~* ^/agent-d-ccp/dev/(.*) {
   proxy_set_header HOST $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header x-apigw-api-id XXXX;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

   set $backend XXXX;
   proxy_pass $backend/dev/$is_args$args;
}
```

I've tried the above but just doesn't seem to work, does `^/agent-d-ccp/dev/(.*)`

need to be `"^/agent-d-ccp/dev/(.*)/(*.)"` for example ?

Thank you to all who respond.

Answer (score 0):

To share for anyone else having the same issue, see answer below:

```
location ~* ^/agent-d-ccp/(.*) {
   proxy_set_header HOST $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header x-apigw-api-id XXXX;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

   set $backend XXXXX;
   proxy_pass $backend/$1$is_args$args;
}
```